# Javascript regexp to capitalize any occurance of a, b, or c in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do a string replace that would map

```
catch the ball
```

to

```
CAtCh the BAll
```

Whats the proper syntax for specifying explicitly that a->A, b->B and c->C?

Comment: Do you need to use regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `.replace()` and use a function to uppercase the found matches.

```
var str = 'catch the ball';
str.replace(/[abc]/g, function(match){
    return match.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: @canon: That's what I do.

Comment: nice, thanks!  didn't realize replace could take a function as the second arg.

Comment: @asutherland: Yep!  You can do that :-D  Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var s = "catch the ball";
var r = s.replace(/[abc]/g, function($0) { return $0.toUpperCase(); });
//=> CAtCh the BAll
```